# QT ROS - RVIZ point click + output

Tags: c++, qt, ros

Can someone tell me how to make possible point click in my rviz that is embedded in my qt application and get the coordinates? Need to tell the robot where should it go.

my code:

```
  rviz_render = new rviz::RenderPanel;
  rviz_manager = new rviz::VisualizationManager(rviz_render);
  rviz_render->initialize( rviz_manager->getSceneManager(), rviz_manager );
  rviz_manager ->initialize();
  ui->rviz_layout->addWidget(rviz_render);
  map_display = rviz_manager->createDisplay( "rviz/Map", "adjustable map", true );
  map_display->subProp("Topic")->setValue("/map");
```

rostopic list shows /clicked_point but there are no data if i echo it